# TeamCity 1 agent 2 servers

Tags: teamcity

Our TeamCity (TC) server sometimes goes down (and we actually don't have much control over it), so we are thinking on having a backup server to switch to in case of the main server is offline.

One way to achieve that is to install 2 agents on each build machine, that should be fine since they will not work in parallel.

But is there a way to share 1 build agent between 2 TC servers?

Comment: I wonder what is the reason of the server going down. If it's not intended, hope TeamCity issues (if any) were reported to JetBrains.

Comment: I think reasons are not connected with TC server itself but with some infrastructure problems that cause the server to crash.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch agent to another server by changing serverUrl property in the agent's conf\buildAgent.properties file. Upon the change, the agent will reconnect to the server specified. However, most probably all sources in the checkout directories will be checked out anew and you will have an overhead of clean checkout on each server switch.

Comment: I suppose that the authorization token is also must be changed along with changing serverUrl, otherwise I assume the agent will hang in "Unauthorized" state.